# rockmongo not allowing to submit query

Tags: php

when i select the mongodb database from rockmongo and selecting a table any if try to run any query error message as "You don't have permission to access /rockmongo/index.php on this server."

while on shell I am able to run everything

Comment: can anyone faces the same problem please help

Comment: if anyone not able to understand my question then this is his problem not mine

Comment: question is so simple pls understand it first the try to vote or answer

Comment: The problem is not rockmongo but your webserver, it is configured incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Use RoboMongo http://robomongo.org/, it needs zero configuration to get it up and running.
I have used RockMongo previously and found that it has usability issues.